# decimal ascii value for unsigned char array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, qt

How to convert char array to its equivalent ascii decimal array ? I tried in QT using QString and QbyteArray. But it is not working.

i/p: "1,9,10,2"

o/p:  "4944574449484450"  (1's ascii decimal value is 49, 
                            , ascii decimal value is 44, 
                            9's ascii decimal value is 57, and so on..).

Comment: It already is. Are you having trouble printing it?

Comment: yes, In debugger it is showing the values. But I print it , it is showing something different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work

```
char arr[] = {'1','9','2'};
std::vector<int> vec(size); //size of the char array - in this case 3
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   vec[i] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: why not add `std:size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char);`?

Comment: It is not necessary to cast `char` when assigned to `int`

Comment: With respect to `int* ptr = new int[size]`, may I pitch [`std::vector<int> vec(size);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ?

Answer (score 4):

> How to convert char array to its equivalent ascii decimal array ?

You do not, it is already stored that way. If you want to print your array as decimal numbers for ASCII just output it accordingly (as integers):

```
char str[] = "1,9,10,2";
for( const char *s = str; *s; ++s ) std::cout << static_cast<int>( *s ) << ","; 
// just output number instead of character
```

`char` in C++ is a numerical type similar to `int`, difference is `std::ostream` outputs `char` as a symbol and `int` and other integer types as integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this way. It's C++ but it will work in C with proper includes and printf in place of std:cout.

```
int main() {
    char input[] = "1,9,10,2";
    char output[3*sizeof(input) + 1];

    output[0] = '\0';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        sprintf(output, "%s%d", output, input[i]);
    }

    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    std::cout << output << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Followed some hint from @Nathan, it should be better now...

Comment: @latedeveloper I'm sorry you are not able to run it. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: `char output[2*strlen(input) + 1];` is a VLA and is not standard C++.

Comment: @Nitro What Nathan said.

Comment: @NathanOliver right... I guess you may replace "strlen" with "sizeof"...

Comment: Still it is a very brittle solution.  You are basically using the assumption that the characters are mapped to values in the range of [10, 99].  If that is ever not the case then problems ensue.

Comment: by the way, as it is constant, probably my compiler does not complain even if I ask --std=c++0x

Comment: you're totally right, I quickly copied the code with %X and when replaced to %d I forgot it; also output shall be initialised to 0, at least the first element.

Comment: You need better compiler flags.  [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/140c992a28be47cc)

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver, "-pedantic" did the trick. I edited the proposed solution to mitigate the issues you kindly spotted

Comment: you think I better remove it?